# python numpy linalg solver: Wrong answer

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, linear-algebra

I having problems with np.linalg.solve ( and i have tried with scipy too) but the answer is wrong for some linear system. A sample of a system that is being generated in my program:

> Matrix A:
>
> [[7.03894408e+00 1.34629120e+10 2.00000000e+10 1.14564392e+10 1.82002747e+10 1.73205081e+10]
>    [1.34629120e+10 7.03894408e+00 1.82002747e+10 2.00000000e+10 2.23606798e+10 2.07665597e+10]
>    [2.00000000e+10 1.82002747e+10 7.03894408e+00 1.67705098e+10 1.67705098e+10 2.23606798e+10]
>    [1.14564392e+10 2.00000000e+10 1.67705098e+10 7.03894408e+00 1.73205081e+10 1.34629120e+10]
>    [1.82002747e+10 2.23606798e+10 1.67705098e+10 1.73205081e+10 7.03894408e+00 1.95256242e+10]
>    [1.73205081e+10 2.07665597e+10 2.23606798e+10 1.34629120e+10 1.95256242e+10 7.03894408e+00]]
>
> Vector b:
>
> [5.49316406e+42 9.62786249e+22 5.49316406e+42 8.66507624e+23 1.38770661e+25 7.66220239e+24]
>
> Vector x from x = np.linalg.solve(A, b)
>
> [-4.06597524e+32  2.80218361e+32 -2.68178425e+32  2.82035894e+32 1.75304606e+32  3.82470510e+31]
>
> A*x from np.dot(A, x) that should be equal to b
>
> [ 5.49316406e+42  9.28455029e+26  5.49316406e+42  6.18970020e+26 -6.18970020e+26 -1.23794004e+27]

for some systems there are more numbers of elements equal in both vectors b and A*x

> some verifications:
>
> conditional number: np.linalg.cond(A) = 11.283698804140434
>
> determinant of A: np.linalg.det(A) = -1.146617874355366e+62
>
> norm of A: np.linalg.norm(A) = 99310120330.20604
>
> norm of inv(A): np.linalg.norm(np.linalg.inv(A)) = 1.6365102872452848e-10

Some systems are ok and the solver gives the right answer.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer you are getting is *not* wrong. Indeed, comparing the original `b` to the reconstructed `br` ...

```
A
# array([[7.03894408e+00, 1.34629120e+10, 2.00000000e+10, 1.14564392e+10,
#         1.82002747e+10, 1.73205081e+10],
#        [1.34629120e+10, 7.03894408e+00, 1.82002747e+10, 2.00000000e+10,
#         2.23606798e+10, 2.07665597e+10],
#        [2.00000000e+10, 1.82002747e+10, 7.03894408e+00, 1.67705098e+10,
#         1.67705098e+10, 2.23606798e+10],
#        [1.14564392e+10, 2.00000000e+10, 1.67705098e+10, 7.03894408e+00,
#         1.73205081e+10, 1.34629120e+10],
#        [1.82002747e+10, 2.23606798e+10, 1.67705098e+10, 1.73205081e+10,
#         7.03894408e+00, 1.95256242e+10],
#        [1.73205081e+10, 2.07665597e+10, 2.23606798e+10, 1.34629120e+10,
#         1.95256242e+10, 7.03894408e+00]])
b
# array([5.49316406e+42, 9.62786249e+22, 5.49316406e+42, 8.66507624e+23,
#        1.38770661e+25, 7.66220239e+24])

br = A@np.linalg.solve(A,b)

abserr = np.sqrt((br-b)@(br-b))
relerr = abserr / np.sqrt(b@b) 
relerr
# 4.914258035606803e-16
```

... we get a relative error that is about 2.2 times machine precision ...

```
np.finfo(float).eps
# 2.220446049250313e-16
```

... which is actually quite accurate.

Comment: Thanks, i got it! I got confused because i was verifying the solution with np.allclose that gives False and you have proved it's correct. Thank you.